# Mesos DC/OS how to configure multiple zones in 1.9

Tags: configuration, mesos, mesosphere, zone

I want to split upp my agent nodes in multiple zones depending on HW the agent nodes is running on. How do i add Zones in the setup configuration when installing?

And can a agent node be in multiple zones at the same time? both zone a and b or just one?

Mesos install page 1.9:

> All agents within a zone should be tagged with an attribute (e.g., zone:us-east-1a )

current config:

```
---
agent_list:
- 10.0.0.1
- 10.0.0.2
- 10.0.0.3
bootstrap_url: file:///opt/dcos_install_tmp
cluster_name: DC/OS
exhibitor_storage_backend: static
ip_detect_path: genconf/ip-detect
master_discovery: static
master_list:
- 10.0.0.3
process_timeout: 10000
public_agent_list:
- 10.0.0.5
resolvers:
- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.4.4
ssh_key_path: genconf/ssh_key
ssh_port: 22
ssh_user: centos
```

Comment: I have tried  some variants but all failed, one example i tried was:
agent_list:
  - 10.0.0.27
    zone:us-east-1a

results in:
Validation of configuration parameters failed:
agent_list: Invalid IPv4 addresses in list: 10.0.0.27 zone:us-east-1a

How do you add attributs? is it not two spaces similar two how it done in rexray_config or dns_forward_zones

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this 6 months ago... but if you are still using DC/OS 1.9 and seeking an answer:

I believe the issue you are seeing with zones is due to the fact that the Mesos attributes are not set in the cluster's `config.yaml` file, but instead on a file that lives on each host node.

TL;DR you need to create or edit `/var/lib/dcos/mesos-slave-common` on each agent to contain a list of Mesos attributes separated via semi colon as such: `MESOS_ATTRIBUTES=<key>:<value>;<key>:<value>`

And as an example (you can create any key:values you would like):
`MESOS_ATTRIBUTES=aws_instance_type:m4.xlarge;aws_availability_zone:us-east-1b`

The next step is to remove the slave state and restart the agent. This will allow you to see (and restrict offers to) these attributes. Note that removing the latest slave state *will* kill any running tasks on the agent because Mesos sees addition of Mesos attributes as an agent re-registration event.

`systemctl stop dcos-mesos-slave
rm -f /var/lib/mesos/slave/meta/slaves/latest
systemctl start dcos-mesos-slave`

The explicit DC/OS documentation on updating agents:
https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.9/administering-clusters/update-a-node/

How to launch Marathon tasks using those attributes:
https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/blob/master/docs/docs/constraints.md

Hope this helps!